# SASS support for Play Framework with Scala 2.13

Tags: scala, sass, playframework, sbt

We are currently trying to update our Play project to Scala 2.13. For SASS support we included sbt-sassify according to the documentation.

During the upgrade progress we noticed that sbt-sassify is only available for Scala 2.12. The Play docs do not suggest any alternative.

I just posted an issue at the plugins github page asking if support for 2.13 will come but as the last changes to the project are over a year old I have doubts there will be a timely reaction.

Has anyone else have this problem? Any ideas for replacements? Similar plugins like sbt-sass or play-sass seem to be rather dead and have no current artifacts in jcenter or similar repos.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about that. SBT 1.x plugins are only available for Scala 2.12 in general.